# Visual Studio Command

Tags: visual-studio, command

There is a way after you "Go to Definition" to push a hotkey to bring you back to where you were last at. There is another one to bring you back to the definition. It is not limited to "Go to Definition" though.

I helps you trace your path through code. I use to use it but after a few month stint away from programming I seem to have forgot it.

What are the commands? I have looked around the internet and I don't know a better group to ask. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl+'-' and Ctrl+Shirt+'-' are the commands. Thank you mandrill for Ctrl+'-' helped me figure out the other one.

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl+'-', also known as `View.NavigateBackward`